# How to remove all padding from Label?

Tags: apache-flex, label, padding

I am trying to remove all the padding from a Label contained in an HBox.  I set paddingTop and paddingBottom to 0 in both the Label and HBox but there is still quite a bit of padding.  I also tried setting verticalGap to 0 on HBox.  If I just have a checkbox in the HBox the padding is removed fine.

Comment: Can you post some of your code?

Comment: I've had this issue in the past, too. Usually it ends up being padding inherited from one of the parent controls. Can you post the MXML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint - padding can be negative.

Comment: Yeah, I tried padding -2 which seems to help although it doesn't seem as "clean."  I would like to set it to 0 if that's possible.

Answer (score 1):

Question seems rather old, but recently I faced same problem and solution was replacing

```
<s:Label>
     some text
</s:Label>
```

(which gives about 190px of unwanted left padding)
with

```
<s:Label text="some text" />
```

which works great!

Answer (score 0):

May be there is a padding for the layout of the HBox?